# How to get comfortable with documentation?

Tags: python, opencv, documentation

I am a novice and I google every little problem I have. Sometimes the answer might be easily availible but I seem to go over easier fixes like blogs or stackoverflow.

I'm curious as to how the rest of you go about solving your problems.

The reason why I ask this is because I'm tired of writing hackey code strung along from sources. It seems like the biggest hurdle is that I don't understand how to find what I'm looking for in the documentation directly.

Sorry, if this doesn't belong here. Still new!

Comment: if this question is regarding opencv, it's better to go through their [examples](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) along with the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/index.html). A lot of blog tutorials exist which may be helpful as well. I think opencv is well documented, so finding anything here shouldn't be troublesome.

Comment: there's nothing bad in using the fastest and easiest solution to a problem. But keep in mind that you don't raise your own skills and value if you don't understand the things you search and copy from the internet. Reading documentation for example in opencv will help you to understand and to get the whole potential (e.g. all kind of different parameters) of a function. Keep in mind that, for some libearies/devices/etc, there might not be any code samples online. The more experience in problem solving, the better you'll be able to solve things yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give you my answer, which *really* isn't from a master, but someone with a similar question not too long ago.

First, I don't think documentation is going to do much to help you become "less hacky." Yes, if you read the entire Python docs you will pick up some useful things, but if you're like most people you will probably just be overwhelmed and forget most of what you have read.

Googling is not a bad thing, especially if you are learning alone - in fact, it might be one of the best ways to learn. The docs aren't necessarily better than SO or Google - docs are also not generally geared so much at helping you solve problems as other sources are. The less common the thing you are trying to do, the more the docs will help.

If you have someone you know that is also learning, [pair programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming) (combined with Googling) can be effective; I understand it is also how a lot leading companies get their programmers to work.

If you are looking for something a bit more "high level," I would read something on test-driven and especially [behaviourally-driven development](https://blog.testlodge.com/what-is-bdd/) in your target language(s). Test-writing is an extremely important skill,  helps your code be "cleaner" and [DRYer](https://dzone.com/articles/is-your-code-dry-or-wet), and what no one tells you starting out is that most of the lines of (modern) commercial code-bases are *mostly* tests. To my mind, moving out of "hacky" is largely learning to deal with design problems, which you can do most easily by learning test-driven development.

You can also try to learn a bit more about common design patterns through (1) "cookbooks" (eg. [the Python cookbook](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/), Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, Two Scoops of Django) or (2) doing math/logic problems so that you understand how to boil a problem down into its nuts and bolts. A lot of the hack events on HackerRank, for example, really come down to removing [Os](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) by thinking through a problem and simplifying algorithms which requires high-level mathematical / logical (i.e. proofs) reasoning abilities.

There are also some good (free/cheap) online courses for this sort of thing (eg. [Agile Development Using Ruby on Rails](https://www.edx.org/course/agile-development-using-ruby-rails-uc-berkeleyx-cs169-1x-1)) which might be worth your while to check out.

Fundamentally though, solving problems, with code or not, is a creative exercise. There is *nothing* wrong with "stringing together" solutions from various sources - just ask an artist if they generally work with or without "inspiration" from other works, the world, etc. They usually do. It's not all meant to come from you and only you.

Finally, someone will probably give you flack about the nature of the question you have asked here. SO questions are supposed to elicit generally non-subjective answers... unless things have changed a lot.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind reply. I will keep referring back to this for a very long time I feel.